# Swiftui how to open page as in segue type model

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to navigate my page and open it like this

[image]

I was doing this in my previous app by performSegue like this

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
```

But now i am using SwiftUI so i need to know how can i achieve this

I am calling my page simple like this

```
NavigationLink(destination: LoginScreenView()) {
    Text("Go To Next Step")
}
```

And the other page is

```
struct LoginScreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}

struct LoginScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginScreenView()
            .previewDevice("iPhone 11")
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.portrait)
    }
}
```

I was learning some couse on udemy that use UIView but I am now using SwiftUI and stuck on this navigation how can I achieve this type of model navigation on this(Simple Navigation is wokring fine)

Comment: You need to use `.sheet` to open screen in that way

Answer (score 0):

Use `.sheet`

```
// for example
NavigationView{}.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
    LoginScreenView()
}
```

Here `showingSheet` is a state:

```swift
@State private var showingSheet = false
```

Set this state to `true`, to open a new page.